Why is terminal singularity on surface smooth
I have seen this statement in many places but no proof of it. In particular on Wikipedia page it says terminal singularity has cxdimension 3 so it is smooth on surfaces and isolated on threefold. What is the proof of it? I suspect it is some use of adjunction.

Let $\mu: Y \to X$ be a resolution of singularities for a terminal surface $X$, and assume $Y$ is minimal(ie. contains no exceptional $(-1)$-curves). By assumption, $K_{Y/X}$ is effective and its support contains all the exceptional divisors. To conclude, it then suffices to show $K_{Y/X} = 0$.
By the negativity lemma, to do so, it suffices to show that $K_{Y/X}$ is $\mu$-nef, and for this it suffices to show $K_Y$ intersects nonnegatively with any $\mu$-exceptional irreducible curve $C \subset Y$.
To this end, we note that $C^2 < 0$ by the Hodge Index Theorem (cf. Hartshorne exercise IV.5.4(b) or exercise IV.5.7.). Hence, by minimality we must have $C^2 \leq -2$ or $p_a(C) \geq 1$. Then, adjunction and these inequalities imply $$K_Y.C = 2p_a(C) - 2 - C^2 \geq 0.$$
